# ASP.NET GridView not showing updated data from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a page where users can search for a PO Number and it will pull up the relevant data for that order from a DataSource that is a SQL database.  I have a field in the database, OrderStatus, where I have updated the value but it is not reflecting that information in the GridView on the page.

Here is my aspx page - the field in the GridView that isn't showing up is in the "gridview' with an ID of "OrderGridView" - the field is "OrderStatus":

```
<asp:gridview id="OrderGridView" CssClass="orderSearchOrderHeaderGridView" autogeneratecolumns="False" DataKeyNames="OrderID" emptydatatext="No data available." allowpaging="True" runat="server" OnRowCommand="OrderGridView_RowCommand">
                <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridViewAltRow" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="OrderID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("OrderID").ToString().Trim()%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PONumber" HeaderText="PO Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.OrderChannel" HeaderText="Order Channel" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.OrderType" HeaderText="Order Type" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.FulfillmentLines" HeaderText="Fulfillment Lines" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.PrintLines" HeaderText="Print Lines" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.FoundationOrderID" HeaderText="Monarch Order ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.FoundationJobID" HeaderText="Monarch Job ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderHeader.OrderStatus" HeaderText="Order Status" />
                    <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="View Order Details" Text="View Details" CommandName="viewDetails" ButtonType="Button" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:gridview>
```

Here is my code-behind related to the search button that they push to find the results and pull up data:

```
        protected void BtnOrderSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OrderGridView.DataSource = null;
                OrderGridView.DataBind();

                OrderShipToGridView.DataSource = null;
                OrderShipToGridView.DataBind();
                OrderShipToGridView.Visible = false;

                OrderLinesGridView.DataSource = null;
                OrderLinesGridView.DataBind();
                OrderLinesGridView.Visible = false;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrderSearchTextbox.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    // Pull in the relevant text for the PO Number and use it to run the RetrieveOrdersByPO function
                    string orderPoNumber = OrderSearchTextbox.Text;
                    Dictionary<int, Order> orderSearch = Functions.RetrieveOrdersByPO(orderPoNumber);

                    // Populate the gridview with the values and make the 1st column, OrderID, not visible
                    OrderGridView.DataSource = orderSearch.Values;
                    OrderGridView.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('No PO number entered.  Please enter a valid PO number and try again.'); location.href='ordersearch.aspx'</script>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Add exception handling / messaging for an invalid PO number
                if (ex is ArgumentException)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Unable to find an order or job with that order / PO Number.  Please verify the order number being entered is correct.  If so, please send an email to HelpDesk@visionsfirst.com with the order number and state that it is not available in the Insight Portal.'); location.href='ordersearch.aspx'</script>");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

For the event, BtnOrderSearch_Click, I'm finding the order ID that is listed in the database using a stored procedure that finds the relevant information in the database.  After that, I'm binding the datasource to the SQL database and pulling down the relevant order line information.  I know the database is working properly because new orders are coming in and populating the database every day.  The problem is that if I update the value of the "OrderStatus" field in the database, it does not reflect it on the page's GridView and I'm not sure why.

What am I missing? Is there something I did wrong? I found similar issues but nothing exactly like this and can't figure out what's wrong.

I've searched low and high on the internet but most issues were solved by binding the data.  Someone referenced !IsPostBack but I'm calling the data on button click so I would think that would initiate a fresh pull of data from the database.

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code here to just the code relevant to the problem? Do we need to see all those gridviews and code associated with them?

Comment: @JonP - Done.  Sorry, I just thought anyone reviewing may want to see everything since there is not a lot.  I've cut the code down to the ASPX page for the gridview and the code behind for the search button.

Comment: Check the value with a breakpoint here : `Dictionary<int, Order> orderSearch = Functions.RetrieveOrdersByPO(orderPoNumber);`. If the value is not the changed value then something is going on in the `RetrieveOrdersByPO` method. Are the DB results cached at all, if  so , make sure the cache is updated after the DB has been updated

Comment: Jon -- the grid view is populating with the data.  It's almost as if it's using CACHED results somehow but I don't know how.  I also don't know what to do differently to force an update other than binding.